# Using data from WorkbookQuery directly in vba

Tags: excel, vba, oledb, powerquery

I have an existing data connection in my excel work book.

I have come across code that can query against that data connection while loading it to a worksheet:

```
With currentSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & query.Name _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdDefault
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & query.Name & "]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

source https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/VBA-to-automate-Power-956a52d1

via [How to automate a power query in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386600/how-to-automate-a-power-query-in-vba/51641109)

And also this from the same source, which is essentially the same thing:

```
Sub LoadToWorksheetAndModel(query As WorkbookQuery, currentSheet As Worksheet) 
    ' Let's load the query to the Data Model 
    LoadToDataModel query 
     
    ' Now we can load the data to the worksheet 
    With currentSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=4, Source:=ActiveWorkbook. _ 
        Connections("Query - " & query.Name), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).TableObject 
        .RowNumbers = False 
        .PreserveFormatting = True 
        .PreserveColumnInfo = False 
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True 
        .RefreshStyle = 1 
        .ListObject.DisplayName = Replace(query.Name, " ", "_") & "_ListObject" 
        .Refresh 
    End With 
End Sub 
 
Sub LoadToDataModel(query As WorkbookQuery) 
     
    ' This code loads the query to the Data Model 
    ThisWorkbook.Connections.Add2 "Query - " & query.Name, _ 
        "Connection to the '" & query.Name & "' query in the workbook.", _ 
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & query.Name _ 
        , """" & query.Name & """", 6, True, False 
 
End Sub
```

But this loads the data to a worksheet, rather than keeping the data in a VBA object.

I would like to efficiently query against this connection and load the result to a variable for further use in VBA without it ever touching a worksheet.

Specifically, I would like to be able to do things like pull all unique values from a column in the data connection into a variable. And I would like to further filter the data in the connection before writing it to a worksheet (while preserving the original data so it can be re-queried).

Comment: You can look into `ADODB.Recordset` objects: [ADO Recordsets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordset-object-ado?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I will look into that. Hopefully it's the direction I need to get me going.