# VBA: Create PivotCache From WorkbookQuery

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I'm trying to create a PivotCache using a WorkbookQuery and I want to do this without loading my source data into the Workbook. I've done this before by using a WorkbookConnection, however, my data comes from a power query and I don't think I can create a WorkbookConnection from that. I've attached some code to illustrate the problem below:

```
Sub Main()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim power_query As String
    power_query = "let in #table({""Name"", ""Score""}, {{""Betty"", 90.3}, {""Carl"", 89.5}})"

    Dim wbq As WorkbookQuery
    Set wbq = ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add("Example", power_query, "Example Data")

    Dim pvCache As PivotCache
    Set pvCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:=wbq)

    Dim pvTable As PivotTable
    Set pvTable = pvCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ws.Range("A1"))

End Sub
```

I've, also, tried using the OLE DB connection string that's generated from the new WorkbookQuery, pasted below, as my SourceData but it doesn't work either.

```
Dim src As String
src = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Example;Extended Properties="""""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost same as my answer for your last question.

[Use VBA to Output Excel Power Query to ListObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77682335/use-vba-to-output-excel-power-query-to-listobject)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PVTWithQuery()
    ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Query1", Formula:= _
        "let in #table({""Name"", ""Score""}, {{""Betty"", 90.3}, {""Carl"", 89.5}})"
    ThisWorkbook.Connections.Add2 "Query - Query1", _
        "Connection to the 'Query1' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Query1;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , "SELECT * FROM [Query1]", 2
    ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Query1"), Version:=8).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Name & "!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=8
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        With .PivotCache
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Name")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Score"), "Sum of Score", xlSum
    End With    
End Sub
```

[image]

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Connections.Add method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.connections.add?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm776079)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Thank you! It's funny. I did try to create a WorkbookConnection using the WorkbookQuery before, but I must have used the wrong arguments.