# Unpivot code set returns an error in Resize Ubound function

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, powerquery, unpivot

I'm trying to unpivot an array of data. I was able to do this before from a slightly different Source data, thanks to our good sir's help mr. Tim Williams who answered my previous question on this ( [Link to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64615412/how-to-unpivot-a-fixed-number-of-columns-with-vba-just-like-power-query)),  however, now i'm using a slightly different source data.

I was pretty sure that I have to only change the number of columns that will be fixed in

```
p = UnPivotData(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Projects Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
    114, True, True)
```

i.e. 114. But for some reason I get an error in this part

```
.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(p, 1), UBound(p, 2)).Value = p
```

It also does work for some couple of lines and after that the error kicks in. I'm not sure what seem to be the error here. I've been trying to work on this for two days and I'm sleep deprived and frustrated,so as usual, I would really be very happy and appreciate your help on this.

[Here's an extract of the file that i'm working on with it's code.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kckguoYeG5-ERMRPWvgwgXrQC-kZAiTi/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Which error do you get? What is the result of `Debug.Print UBound(p, 1)` and `Debug.Print UBound(p, 2)`?

Comment: Please note that you share a lot of real date including names that should probably not be public! Always anonymize your data before sharing!

Comment: Why not use Power Query itself to do the unpivot?  That functionality is built in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in your data appears `#1837-10-07 17:31:12#`. But Excel cannot display dates before `1900`. Therefore it fails to write that data and aborts.

The problem is the column `DI` in `Projects Data` is formatted as `Date` but there are no dates in it. Fix that number format to `General` and your function works as expected.

Comment: Thank you sir it worked. I never thought excel does consider that with this code. Thank you so much.