# Unique name for Query/Pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a macro that can be used by other people that will import data monthly and create two pivot tables from two Excel workbooks.

The best method I devised is to have the person download the two files into the same folder as this macro-enabled workbook and name them the same for the purpose of querying and pulling the data (i.e. Output1 and Output2) then append with the date and move to a storage folder once they have run the macro and gotten the tables they want. (If I am misunderstanding how querying works and the data needs to remain available in the same location and name for the pivot tables to continue existing please let me know.)
This way I can hardcode the files to pull from and it's minimal effort on their part.

**The problem**
When I record the macro, it makes a static name for each query with

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add
```

Which means that when I run it for the second month, I get an error that the query connection already exists and the macro errors out.

I found this code that is supposed to check if the query already exists, and if it does; delete it, but I can't make it work.

```vb
Dim qry As WorkbookQuery

If DoesQueryExist(TS) Then
    ' Deleting the query
    Set qry = ThisWorkbook.Queries(TS)
    qry.Delete
End If
```

I placed this inside my macro sub.

I wasn't able to find very much on the function "DoesQueryExist".
Is there another solution to instead create unlimited queries with arbitrary names instead of having to check and delete?

Comment: Did you find the function `DoesQueryExist` [here](https://www.msaccessgurus.com/VBA/Code/DAO_DoesTableExist.htm)? First of all, note that's for *Access*.

Comment: I thought VBA was consistent for all Office Apps?
I found it here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386600/how-to-automate-a-power-query-in-vba

Comment: For the most part, VBA is, but each application has its own object model and application specific functions.

Comment: Okay. Darn. So that solution is out, is there a similar thing that can be used for excel or is the idea to find a way to increment on each use or make unique the query names the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the code for `DoesQueryExist`:

```
Function DoesQueryExist(ByVal queryName As String) As Boolean
    ' Helper function to check if a query with the given name already exists
    Dim qry As WorkbookQuery
    
    If (ThisWorkbook.Queries.Count = 0) Then
        DoesQueryExist = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    For Each qry In ThisWorkbook.Queries
        If (qry.Name = queryName) Then
            DoesQueryExist = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    DoesQueryExist = False
End Function
```

Sourced from [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20200318170443/https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/VBA-to-automate-Power-956a52d1/file/138238/1/Macro%20and%20VBA%20with%20PQ.xlsm).

Comment: I am having the same problem for the name of the pivot table. Would this be usable to duplicate with the name of the pivot table, or am I going about this all wrong? Some other way to increment titles on each use? I think I see now that the Query can't just be named whatever I want, but I imagine the pivottable can

Comment: You can create a similar helper function to see if a pivot table with a certain name exists.

Comment: Wont that delete my existing pivot table though?
I want to hopefully keep all the pivot tables moving forward

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to delete the existing table. I'm a bit confused as to what your actual general goal is here.

Comment: Once a month, there is two sets of data I want to make two pivot tables from. I want to create a macro that minimizes the amount of work needed before and after it's run. Then instead of keeping these gigantic files that have a lot of unnecessary data, we just keep the months pivot tables that give us at a glance for the things we actually care about. (extrapolated data though like counts so I can't just remove rows/columns)